# PostgreSQL/PLPGSQL Procedure, that returns variable as column

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a procedure, which inserts a row in a table and then returns an assigned id.

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
UUID Id,
varchar field1,
varchar field2)
```

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_sometable(varchar pfield1, varchar pfield2)
  RETURNS UUID AS  $$
DECLARE
pid UUID;
BEGIN
pid=uuid_generate();
insert into sometable(id, field1, field2) values (pid, pfield1, pfield2);
return pid;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And i want it to use it like that:

```
select pid from insert_sometable('_field1_value', '_field2_value')
```

But now i got no **column name** of its result, so i can't access it in my ESB service.
I want column called "pid" in result set. 
Seems like easy task, but i didn't found any simple solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a function whose return value is atomic (not a row) in the `FROM` clause (it's possible, but makes your query less readable). You can add an alias in the `SELECT` clause too:

```
select insert_sometable('_field1_value', '_field2_value') as pid;
```

Comment: Thanks, pozs. You are so fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just trying to alias the returned column name. If so:

```
select pid 
from insert_sometable('_field1_value', '_field2_value') AS inserted_row(pid);
```

PostgreSQL permits you to write shorthand for this for functions that return only one column:

```
select pid 
from insert_sometable('_field1_value', '_field2_value') pid;
```